# My return statements are not giving any output

Tags: python, return

I wrote this code and it's not returning any output, I'm not sure why. As far as I can tell I have the returns correct but obviously since there is no output something is wrong.

```py
def main():
    j = int(input("Enter a number "))
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    yourBirthPlace()
    pentapalooza(j)
    oldEnoughToDrinkInGermany(age)


def yourBirthPlace():
    return "Chicago"
def pentapalooza(j):
    j=j*5
    return j
def oldEnoughToDrinkInGermany(age):
    result=false
    LegalAge = 16
    if age>LegalAge:
        result= true
    return result


main()
```

Comment: Your `main()` function doesn't have return statement.

Comment: Do you expect a result to be printed? Consider using the `print` function.

Comment: In a script expression results aren't automatically printed like in the interpreter.

Comment: I rather think you didn't even try running this code. If you had then you might have noticed the NameError exception

Answer (score 0):

You're missing print statements

```py
print(yourBirthPlace())
print(pentapalooza(j))
print(oldEnoughToDrinkInGermany(age))
```

Comment: Note that this is already covered in our knowledge base -- see [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing) as well as the many questions closed with it as duplicate, and the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), including its bullet point regarding questions "that have been asked and answered many times before".